# Understanding the save method and what it returns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a method that contains the following code.

```
def save_question(content)

  question = Question.new

  question.content = content

  question.save

end
```

When I run this in an if statement

```
if save_question(content)
  puts "Everything is cool"
else
  puts "Something went wrong"
end
```

The method returns `"Everything is cool"`. However if I change the method to this

```
def save_question(content)

  question = Question.new

  question.content = content

  return false unless question.save

end
```

Then the if statement will return `"Something went wrong"`. Am I missing something big here? I thought the save method returns true, which is does, but why does the method return false?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're modifying your method so that it returns `false` or `nil`, which is also falsy.

Your last line now reads

```
return false unless question.save
```

There is no implicit `return true` here. If `question.save` returns true, the `return false` is never executed, and the expression evaluates to `nil`.

Think of it this way: What would you expect this version of the function to return?

```
def save_question(content)
  if !question.save
    return false
  end
end
```

Comment: `pants` -> `false`. That's an interesting typo :)

Comment: I was going to make some point about "just because you're returning false doesn't mean the there's an implicit opposite `return true`; what if you return some arbitrary thing like `"pants"`", but decided it was a mixed message :p

Comment: Ahhh. I get it now. Silly second part question then would be what's a Ruby way to keep the method continue on if save returns true and I have more code below the save method?

Comment: @jason328 I'm not sure what you mean. You'd just keep adding code afterwards, there's nothing wrong with doing so.